# Auto-sklearn feature importance

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, automl

I am trainning a model in autosklearn with ensembling method, And I was wondering If I can get a list of feature importance of the final ensemble model after fitting?

Thanks

Comment: See https://www.featureranking.com/tutorials/machine-learning-tutorials/sk-part-2-feature-selection-and-ranking/